# How to show $\frac{wH^x +(1-w)(1-H)^x}{wL^x +(1-w)(1-L)^x}$ is convex in $x$?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

How do I show that the function $f(x) = \frac{wH^x +(1-w)(1-H)^x}{wL^x +(1-w)(1-L)^x}$ is convex in $x$, where $0 <w<1$ and $0.5 \leq L <H<1$?  Visual inspection in Mathematica suggests this conjecture is true, but I have not been able to make headway by signing the second derivative with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a counterexample (obtained via Desmos) that shows that the convexity claim for the values

$$L=0.9, H=0.95, w=0.1$$

is not true (though they comply with the given constraints).

[image]

Therefore, the asker should restrict the considered range of values.